# how to take an integer from a string in a variable php

Tags: php, html

I have a variable

```
$placement = "1st place"
```

What I want to do is take the number 1 and place it in another variable

```
$placement_num = "1";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible via a few different methods. But what about cases like `"1st place, 2nd place"` -- what would your variable contain then?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That may be irrelevant, we don't know how this string is generated.

Comment: For your simple example, merely calling `intval('1st place')` would return the desired result.

Comment: I tried intval($placement) and it returned zero but it should have been 2

Comment: Nevermind! I realized I had `' '` around my variable, so it was `intval('$placement')` and after removing the `' '` it worked as it should. Thank you! If you answer the question I will check it as a right answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the numerical part is always right at the start of the string, you can just cast to `int`:

```
$str = '1st place';
$num = (int) $str;
var_dump($num);

$str = '4th place';
$num = (int) $str;
var_dump($num);
```

This yields:

```
int(1)
int(4)
```